# For some reason when i put my third image it is not working

Tags: android, background, libgdx

When i made my first few images appear, they worked, but when i put this image it does not work
In my create function it looks like this.

```
  Gogreen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gogreenNow.jpg"));
 greenArea = new TextureRegion(Gogreen, 20, 20, 50, 50);
    //float delaySeconds = 1;
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
position = new Vector2(100, 50);
pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
batch = new SpriteBatch();
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

size2 = new Vector2(trash.getWidth() ,trash.getHeight() );
//size2.y = trash.getHeight();
//size2.x = trash.getWidth();
size = new Vector2(paper.getWidth() ,paper.getHeight());

bounds= new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
bounds2= new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);
```

Surprisingly the images called trash and paper work but the image called gogreen does not work. And in the render loop it looks like this:

```
batch.begin();
        batch.draw(Gogreen, 10, 10);
        batch.draw(greenArea, 50, 10);
        batch.draw(Gogreen, 50, 50);
        batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
        batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);
        font.setScale(3);
        font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch, str, 200,900);

                batch.end();

                font.dispose();
```

I also have another quick question, using the go green image(the one that is not working) I need to make a background image, does anybody know how? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i got the answer, My width and height needed to be factors of two, and i was using the wrong path. My image was suppose to be in the assets folder but it was placed somewhere else.